# Кодревью: модульные тесты для простых доменных объектов

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода, тестирование

И снова я с темой инспекции кода, почитав книги по модульному тестированию.

Проект .NetFramework 4.6.1, фреймворк тестирования - nUnit.

У меня есть два простых класса в доменной модели: `Order` и `OrderPosition`:

Заказ:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace MyCompanyName.MyProjectName.Domain
{
    public class Order
    {
        public Order(int id, DateTime created, IList<OrderPosition> orderPositions)
        {
            this.Id = id;
            this.Created = created;
            this.OrderPositions = orderPositions;
        }

        public int Id { get; }

        public DateTime Created { get; }

        public ICollection<OrderPosition> OrderPositions { get; }

        public int PositionsCount
        {
            get { return this.OrderPositions.Count; }
        }

        public decimal OrderPrice
        {
            get { return this.OrderPositions.Sum(x => x.TotalPrice); }
        }
    }
}
```

Позиция заказа:

```
using System;

namespace MyCompanyName.MyProjectName.Domain
{
    public class OrderPosition
    {
        private int _quantity;
        private string _title;

        public OrderPosition(int id, int orderId, string title, int quantity, decimal unitPrice, decimal discount)
        {
            this.Id = id;
            this.OrderId = orderId;
            this.Title = title;
            this.Quantity = quantity;
            this.UnitPrice = unitPrice;
            this.Discount = discount;
        }

        public int Id { get; }

        public int OrderId { get; }

        public string Title
        {
            get { return this._title; }
            private set
            {
                if (value != null && value.Length > 20)
                    throw new ArgumentException(nameof(this.Title));

                this._title = value;
            }
        }

        public int Quantity
        {
            get { return this._quantity; }
            private set
            {
                if (value < 1)
                    throw new ArgumentException(nameof(this.Quantity));

                this._quantity = value;
            }
        }

        public decimal UnitPrice { get; }

        public decimal Discount { get; }

        public decimal TotalPrice
        {
            get { return this.UnitPrice * this.Discount * this.Quantity; }
        }
    }
}
```

(Я несколько упростил пример из реального предложения, убрав справочник товаров, вспомогательные поля чтобы сильно не раздувать код вопроса, но демо-приложение полностью рабочее)

Попробовал написать юнит-тесты для этих классов.

Предварительно замечу по соглашению о наименовании классов: я использовал реже встречающийся вариант, когда имя тестового класса идёт по шаблону `<НазваниеТестируемого класса>Test_<тестируемый метод>`.

В первую очередь я набросал несколько тестов на автосвойства без всякой логики, например Order.Id, Order.Created, OrderPosition.UnitPrice, OrderPosition.Discount.

Приведу лишь пару примеров, они все однотипные.

Для OrderPosition.UnitPrice такой тест:

```
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace MyCompanyName.MyProjectName.Domain.Tests.Unit
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class OrderPositionTests_UnitPrice : OrderPositionTestsBase
    {
        [Test]
        public void Always_SetProp()
        {
            const decimal unitPrice = 123M;

            var result = NewOrderPosition(1, 2, "asdf", 3, unitPrice, 0.1M);

            Assert.AreEqual(unitPrice, result.UnitPrice);
        }
    }
}
```

Где в базовый класс вынесена логика инициализации объекта:

```
namespace MyCompanyName.MyProjectName.Domain.Tests.Unit
{
    public class OrderPositionTestsBase
    {
        protected static OrderPosition NewOrderPosition(int id, int orderId, string title, int quantity, decimal unitPrice, decimal discount)
        {
            return new OrderPosition(id, orderId, title, quantity, unitPrice, discount);
        }
    }
}
```

По рекомендациям Ошероува выносить инициализацию в фабричный метод.

Аналогично для Order.Id, там просто чуть больше данных конструируется:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace MyCompanyName.MyProjectName.Domain.Tests.Unit
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class OrderTests_Id : OrderTestsBase
    {
        [Test]
        public void Always_SetProp()
        {
            const int orderId = 1;

            var result = NewOrder(orderId, new DateTime(), new List<OrderPosition> { NewOrderPosition(1, orderId, "asdf", 2, 1234M, 0.1M) });

            Assert.AreEqual(orderId, result.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

И так же в базовый класс вынесена логика конструирования объекта:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MyCompanyName.MyProjectName.Domain.Tests.Unit
{
    public class OrderTestsBase
    {
        protected static Order NewOrder(int id, DateTime created, IList<OrderPosition> orderPositions)
        {
            return new Order(id, created, orderPositions);
        }

        protected static OrderPosition NewOrderPosition(int id, int orderId, string title, int quantity, decimal unitPrice, decimal discount)
        {
            return new OrderPosition(id, orderId, title, quantity, unitPrice, discount);
        }
    }
}
```

Далее я написал тесты для свойств, содержащих какую-никакую но логику.

Для поля "количество" я проверяю, что оно не может содержать нуль или отрицательные числа:

```
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace MyCompanyName.MyProjectName.Domain.Tests.Unit
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class OrderPositionTests_Quantity : OrderPositionTestsBase
    {
        [Test]
        public void ZeroValue_ThrowsArgumentException()
        {
            const int quantity = 0;

            var ex = Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(() => NewOrderPosition(1, 2, "asdf", quantity, 1234M, 0.1M));

            StringAssert.Contains(nameof(OrderPosition.Quantity), ex.Message);
        }

        [Test]
        public void NegativeValue_ThrowsArgumentException()
        {
            const int quantity = -1;

            var ex = Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(() => NewOrderPosition(1, 2, "asdf", quantity, 1234M, 0.1M));

            StringAssert.Contains(nameof(OrderPosition.Quantity), ex.Message);
        }

        [Test]
        public void PositiveValue_SetProp()
        {
            const int quantity = 1;

            var result = NewOrderPosition(1, 2, "asdf", quantity, 1234M, 0.1M);

            Assert.AreEqual(quantity, result.Quantity);
        }
    }
}
```

Для строки "наименование позиции товара" я контролирую длину строки:

```
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace MyCompanyName.MyProjectName.Domain.Tests.Unit
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class OrderPositionTests_Title : OrderPositionTestsBase
    {
        [Test]
        public void NullValue_IsCorrect()
        {
            const string title = null;

            var result = NewOrderPosition(1, 2, title, 2, 1234M, 0.1M);

            Assert.IsNull(result.Title);
        }

        [Test]
        public void ShortStringValue_SetsProp()
        {
            const string title = "asdf";

            var result = NewOrderPosition(1, 2, title, 2, 1234M, 0.1M);

            Assert.AreEqual(title, result.Title);
        }

        [Test]
        public void TooLongValue_ThrowsArgumentException()
        {
            const string title = "123456789012345678901";

            var ex = Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(() => NewOrderPosition(1, 2, title, 2, 1234M, 0.1M));

            StringAssert.Contains(nameof(OrderPosition.Title), ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

После этого у меня остались расчётные поля.

Для OrderPosition это TotalPrice:

```
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace MyCompanyName.MyProjectName.Domain.Tests.Unit
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class OrderPositionTests_TotalPrice : OrderPositionTestsBase
    {
        [Test]
        public void UnitPriceDiscontinued_Always_CalculatesTotalPrice()
        {
            var orderPosition = NewOrderPosition(1, 2, "", 2, 10M, 0.1M);

            var totalPrice = orderPosition.TotalPrice;

            Assert.AreEqual(2M, totalPrice);
        }
    }
}
```

Для Order это PositionsCount:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace MyCompanyName.MyProjectName.Domain.Tests.Unit
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class OrderTests_PositionsCount : OrderTestsBase
    {
        [Test]
        public void Always_ReturnsCount()
        {
            const int orderId = 1;
            var orderPositions = new List<OrderPosition>
            {
                NewOrderPosition(1, orderId, "test", 1, 10M, 0.1M),
            };
            var order = new Order(orderId, new DateTime(), orderPositions);

            var orderPositionsCount = order.PositionsCount;

            Assert.AreEqual(orderPositions.Count, orderPositionsCount);
        }

        [Test]
        public void Always_ReturnsCount2()
        {
            const int orderId = 1;
            var orderPositions = new List<OrderPosition>
            {
                NewOrderPosition(1, orderId, "test1", 1, 10M, 0.1M),
                NewOrderPosition(2, orderId, "test2", 3, 12M, 0.2M),
            };
            var order = new Order(orderId, new DateTime(), orderPositions);

            var orderPositionsCount = order.PositionsCount;

            Assert.AreEqual(orderPositions.Count, orderPositionsCount);
        }
    }
}
```

и OrderPrice:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace MyCompanyName.MyProjectName.Domain.Tests.Unit
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class OrderTests_OrderPrice : OrderTestsBase
    {
        [Test]
        public void UnitPriceDiscontinued_Always_ReturnsDiscontinuedPrice()
        {
            const int orderId = 1;
            var order = new Order(orderId, new DateTime(), new List<OrderPosition> { NewOrderPosition(1, orderId, "test", 1, 10M, 0.1M) });

            var orderPrice = order.OrderPrice;

            Assert.AreEqual(1M, orderPrice);
        }
    }
}
```

На этом в принципе я решил подвести черту и провести ревью.

В первую очередь меня интересуют следующие вопросы:

- Каких тестов не хватает?
- Какие тесты нужно исключить или переделать?
- Нужно ли как-то отдельно протестировать конструкторы? Если да, то как? Если нет - то почему?
- Есть ли какие-то рекомендации по наименованию тестов?
- Покрывают ли тесты (особенно там где логика или расчёты) все возможные ситуации?
- Какие есть замечания по самому коду тестов?

Также если есть какие-то замечания по самим тестируемым классам - тоже буду признателен за обратную связь.

Answer (score 1):

Громаднейший вопрос.

1. Что касается наименования тестов, то тут использовать правильнее наименования: class Test_НаименованиеТестируемогоКласса (удобнее искать тесты при изменении класса)
2. Что касается наименования методов тестирования тут лучше пользоваться void Test_Наименование(метода/свойства)*In*(Входные параметры, если нужны)*Out*(Что должны получить на выходе)(удобство при поиске нужного теста)
3. При большом количестве моделей данных удобно добавить категорию перед методом:[Category("модель")]void Test_Наименование(метода/свойства)*In*... или даже перед классом - это дает удобство при изменении модели, у вас есть возможность выбрать все тесты связанные с конкретной моделью, такое удобно и при интеграционном тестировании
4. В Assert.AreEqual - добавить текст ошибки, типа Assert.AreEqual(a,b,"ожидалось {0}, в результате выполнения получили {1}",a,b); - такое удобно в дальнейшем для отладки самого теста и конечно по прошествии большого времени вам этот текст поможет понять, а что вы ожидали в итоге.
5. Иногда, чаще всего когда нужна отчетность по выполнению тестов, можно добавлять запись логов, но тут надо быть крайне осторожными, однако в этом есть свои прелести, например, можно автоматизировать отчет о проделанной работе над проектом, либо создать отчет о не прошедших тестах, и получить в одном месте причины не прохождения тестов в проекте.
6. Однако с логгированием не стоит увлекаться, так как тесты должны быть простыми, и легко разбираемыми.
7. Что нужно тестировать? Вопрос весьма спорный, так например я встречал в книгах, что тестировать нужно все публичные методы и свойства, однако если у вас есть просто {get;set;}, что вы тогда будете тестировать? Однако у таких свойств есть обрабочики, наподобие взять из свойства одного объекта и поставить в свойства другого, тогда этот обработчик надо тестировать. Обязательно надо тестировать свойства с внутренней логикой установки и получения на подобие: {get{...}set{...}}
8. На счет покрытия всех ситуаций, тут весьма интересный вопрос, Вы не БОГ! поэтому предвидеть все ситуации в особо сложных случаях не сможете. Однако дополнять тесты на основе пойманных багов. вам никто не запретит, и это даже правильнее, появился баг, написали тест воспроизводящий баг, затем устранили, и протестировали.

Этот ответ не возможно считать полным, однако я постарался максимально четко передать мой ход мыслей при создании тестов.

Comment: Спасибо что оформили ответом, я думаю это пойдёт на пользу популяризации кодревью на stackoverflow.

Comment: Про поясняющий текст в Assert.AreEqual  у Ошероува было объяснение и я с ним совершенно согласен, что фреймворки тестирования вам это прекрасно покажут и без вас: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkY52.png по-моему вполне наглядно. В чужом коде мне тоже не попадалось активное использование этого приёма, поэтому я даже сходу и не могу привести пример, когда это было уместно и повышало читаемость теста.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81046/discussion-on-question-by-a-k-------).