# Простые unit-тесты на проверку пароля

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты, тестирование

Помогите переделать Unit-тест. На форме AdForm  имеется textbox, на который нужно написать два простых unit-теста.
На проверку правильности ввода, и не правильности ввода пароля т.е. два отдельных unit-теста.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код который хочу тестировать:

```
 public void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (maskedTextBox4.Text == "qwerty") // вот это тестить хочу
            {
                AdForm adForm = new AdForm(this);
                adForm.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
        }
```

Мой корявый наброски Unit-тестов:

```
[TestMethod()]
public void login()
{
    AdForm n = new AdForm ();
    string rez = n.insCl("qwerty");
    string exp = "Успешно";
    Assert.AreEqual(rez, exp);
}



[TestMethod]
public void login()
{
    adForm  n = new adForm ();
    n.Text(true,"qwerty");
}



[TestMethod()]
public void login()
{
    AdForm test1 = new AdForm ();
    int a = test1.conv("qwerty");
    Assert.AreEqual(a, 0);
}
```

P.S. Если кто поможет, буду благодарен. Мне бы один правильный вариант Unit-теста на проверку. Дальше сам. Не ругайтесь.

Код формы:

```
namespace roza
{
    public partial class AuthForm : Form
    {
        public AuthForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

            public void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (maskedTextBox4.Text == "qwerty") // вот это тестить хочу
                {
                    AdForm adForm = new AdForm(this);
                    adForm.Show();
                    this.Hide();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Вот так должна выглядеть работа Unit-теста

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тест-->Выполнить-->Все тесты

Comment: Проверка правильности пароля - это ответственность отдельного класса, вам надо тестировать его если вы хотите проверить логику проверки пароля. Если вы хотите тестировать форму, вам надо обратиться к средствам автоматизированного тестирования интерфейсов, которое будет запускать приложение на каждый тест и тыкать кнопки автоматом.  А то, что вы написали, по большому счету, не тестирует ничего.

Comment: У вас должен быть класс, у класса должен быть метод, который принимает все, что надо для идентификации юзера (наверное логин и пароль) и возвращает true/false - результат о том, корректны ли переданные данные или нет. Если у вас такого класса нет - вам надо его написать

Comment: примеров готовых нет, все зависит от требований к вашей программе.

Comment: `простая проверка` - я не знаю, что это значит. Начните писать класс. Добавьте в него метод для проверки. Напишите код проверки.

Comment: `Assert` тут не при чем. Вам нужен класс с логикой проверки логина/пароля. Вот ввел юзер user/pAsswoRd - как ваша программа поймет, есть такой юзер с этим логином/паролем или нет?

Comment: `Assert` нужен для тестирования написанного кода. Если код у вас не написан, то тестировать нечего и `Assert` вам не поможет

Comment: Не редактируйте, пожалуйста вопрос, на который уже даны ответы. Вместо этого, вы можете задать новый вопрос. Я откатил ваши последние правки, потому что они являются вандальными.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Допустим, у вас есть сервис для проверки пароля

```
public class LoginService
{
    public bool Login(string secret)
    {
        return secret == "qwerty";
    }
}
```

И вы используете его на своей форме

```
public class LoginForm : Form
{
    LoginService _loginService;

    public LoginForm(LoginService loginService)
    {
        _loginService = loginService;

        var passwordBox = new TextBox();
        var loginButton = new Button() { Text = "Login", Top = 50 };

        loginButton.Click += (sender, args) =>
        {
            var text = passwordBox.Text;
            if (loginService.Login(text))
                MessageBox.Show("Login sucessed");
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Login failed");
        };

        this.Controls.Add(passwordBox);
        this.Controls.Add(loginButton);
    }
}
```

Создание формы выглядит так:

```
var service = new LoginService();
var form = new LoginForm(service);
form.ShowDialog();
```

Результат выглядит так:

[image: Результат]

Тесты писать надо будет для сервиса, так как только он содержит логику, определяющую, правильный был передан пароль или нет. Пример 2 тестов - позитивный и негативный:

```
[TestMethod()]
public void login_failed()
{
    var loginService = new LoginService();
    var actual = loginService.Login("wrong password");
    var expected = false;
    Assert.AreEqual(actual, expected);
}


[TestMethod()]
public void login_sucessed()
{
    var loginService = new LoginService();
    var actual = loginService.Login("qwerty");
    var expected = true;
    Assert.AreEqual(actual, expected);
}
```

Comment: Коллега, мы с вами опять на вахте? ) Одни и те же вопросы отвечаем )

Comment: @AK походу да, но это хорошо, хотя бы не скучно :)

Comment: @seven7 добавляйте весь код в вопрос, у меня все эти яндекс-диски заблочены корпоративным фаевполом

Comment: @seven7 у меня работодатель очень озабочен безопасностью, я даже картинки не вижу в собственном ответе, потому ни о каких файлообменниках не может быть и речи. Если у вас вопрос по коду - указывайте этот код в вопросе, ссылки на что то куда то бесполезны для меня

Comment: @seven7 в вашем архиве, тот что на яндекс-диске, виндовый антивирус находит троян. Вы уж там проверьтесь на вирусы, ага?

Comment: @seven7 я не знаю, мне антивирус блокирует доступ к этому архиву по понятной причине.

Comment: @seven7 хорошо, я посмотрю и завтра просигнализирую вам

Comment: @seven7 Да, посмотрел, скачать можно [здесь](https://yadi.sk/d/Ko6Ji6lBmH7tKQ)

Comment: @Bulson так может ответом оформите?

Comment: @seven7 если вы знаете, что вам нужно - сделайте это сами или задайте новый вопрос. Мне кажется, код, что вы обсуждаете, уже далеко ушел как от самого вопроса, так и от этого ответа.

Comment: @seven7 в ответах на этот вопрос вам советуют отделять логику от обработки событий нажатия на кнопки. Я показал вам пример, такого разделения: вся логика по работе с паролем находится в отдельном классе `PasswordService`. Такой подход нужен хотя бы для того, чтобы производить тестирование. Вы же уперлись на лоховском варианте проверки пароля прямо в обработчике события `click`. Если вам не нравиться хранение пароля в виде хэша, то метод `PasswordService.IsPasswordCorrect()` достаточно легко изменить для этого.

Comment: @seven7 вы понимаете, что при любом раскладе у вас не будет юнит теста с проверкой `maskedTextBox1.Text` - так как если юнит тест начинает проверять что было введено в текстбоксы, то это уже не юнит тест, а больше интеграционный тест или текст пользовательского интерфейса. То есть ваша просьба по сути выглядит как "сделайте мне зеленое синим"

Comment: @seven7 [здесь](https://yadi.sk/d/pnbUAJEA6_3AbQ)

Comment: @seven7 тестировать формы и их приватные методы, которые возвращают void невозможно. Нет возвращаемых значений - нечего проверять! Тестируемые методы, должны что-то возвращать, они должны быть по крайней мере protected. Для тестирования пользовательских интерфейсов существуют специальные инструменты, только это уже не будет unit тестированием.

Comment: @seven7 [здесь](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H9u_BvmCjuI)

Comment: @Bulson вам уже пора делать это за оплату :)

Comment: @seven7 вам бы самому хотя бы попытаться решить вашу проблему, того, что есть тут в ответах более чем достаточно для этого. Вы уже знаете, что вам надо получить в итоге. Вы знаете, как это получить (см ответы + помощь от Bulson). Так приложите усилия для этого. Если у вас что то снова не получается и есть конкретный вопрос (который отличается от этого вопроса), то задавайте его отдельным вопросом. А так вы просите делать работу за вас, к тому же ещё таким образом, что Bulson даже баллов не этом не получит. И первое и второе тут не приветсвуется

Answer (score 3):

Вся проблема в том, что вы не отделили классы UI (ваши формочки) и бизнес-логику.

Это очень стандартная ошибка новичков: фигачить бизнес-логику прямо в buttonN_click.

Поэтому сначала вы должны научаться разделять логику предметной области от UI - и потом уже писать юнит-тесты на них.

А пока это у вас не будет юнит-тест, это будет что-то ближе к интеграционному тесты, либо юнит-тест, но хрупкий, который зависит и от UI и от фаз луны и от чего-нибудь ещё.

Посмотрите вот [мои примеры юнит-тестов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/863076/213987): у меня в проекте ни одной формы нет, а тесты есть.

Как вам нужно поступить в вашем случае. У вас есть некий класс формы, вам нужно объявить, что этот класс имеет зависимость от некоторого класса, реализующего интерфейс проверки пароля.

Было:

```
public partial class AuthForm : Form
{
    public AuthForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (maskedTextBox4.Text == "qwerty") // вот это тестить хочу
        {
            AdForm adForm = new AdForm(this);
            adForm.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
}
```

Стало:

```
public partial class AuthForm : Form
{
    public AuthForm(IPasswordCheckerService passwordCheckerService)
    {
        this.PasswordCheckerService = passwordCheckerService;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private IPasswordCheckerService PasswordCheckerService { get; set; }

    public void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.PasswordCheckerService.IsPasswordValid(maskedTextBox4.Text)) // вот это тестить хочу
        {
            AdForm adForm = new AdForm(this);
            adForm.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
}

public interface IPasswordCheckerService 
{
    bool IsPasswordValid(string password)
}
```

И вот с этим уже можно работать.

Вы можете создать кучу классов, которые реализуют данный интефейс - от простых, которые возвращают всегда true или которые проверяют что пароль равен какой-либо захардкоженной строке до очень сложных, которые лезут в реестр виндовс, базу данных, облако и т.п.

Вот простой пример класса, реализующего интерфейс:

```
public class SimplePasswordChecker : IPasswordCheckerService
{
    public bool IsPasswordValid(string password)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

А вот простой тест:

```
[Test]
public void IsPasswordValid_PasswordMatch_ReturnsTrue()
{
    // Arrange
    var checker = new SimplePasswordChecker();

    // Act
    var result = checker.IsPasswordValid("qwerty");

    // Assert
    Assert.IsTrue(result);
}

[Test]
public void IsPasswordValid_PasswordMismatch_ReturnsFalse()
{
    // Arrange
    var checker = new SimplePasswordChecker();

    // Act
    var result = checker.IsPasswordValid("asdf");

    // Assert
    Assert.IsFalse(result);
}
```

Разумеется, этот тест "не пройдёт". Как и полагается в TDD мы сначала написали красный тест, потом исправляем код класса SimplePasswordChecker на тот, который пройдёт тест.

Получившиеся классы никак не завязаны на то, какой у вас интерфейс - сегодня это winforms, завтра wpf, веб или мобильное приложение. А бизнес-логика остаётся отдельным проектом в решении, которое не имеет никаких зависимостей. Поэтому все эти классы бизнес-логики сразу отселяйте в отдельный проект и начинайте структурировать своё приложение - это и есть архитектура приложения, когда у вас слои разделяют обязанности, а не валят всё в одну кучу.

PS Как передавать зависимость на конструктор - оставляю вам на самостоятельную проработку. В идеале вообще такие вещи делаются при помощи DI.